# Add a JsonElement to a JsonPatchDocument

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net, system.text.json

I'm working with *creating* `JsonPatchDocument`s ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.jsonpatch.jsonpatchdocument?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) in .NET (as opposed to just accepting through an endpoint). I would really like to be able to use `System.Text.Json` for this as opposed to Newtonsoft.JSON, but I can't figure out equivalent functionality. [Microsoft guidance on replacing JObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#jsondocument-and-jsonelement-compared-to-jtoken-like-jobject-jarray) does not seem to cover this behavior from what I can tell.

At this point in the code I have worked through a JsonDocument, and identified a JsonElement that is new and needs to be added to the patch.

Pulling from the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), here are two example documents and their JSON patch:

```
Start: { "foo": "bar" }
Patch: [{ "op": "add", "path": "/child", "value": { "grandchild": { } } }]
End: {"foo": "bar","child": {"grandchild": { } } }
```

I tried a number of different varieties and didn't save them all. But here are some ways to *not* successfully accomplish this:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch;

// JsonElement element is the change we want to see added in the patch
JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
patchDocument.Add(path, element); // Only the JsonElement property comes through. Gives [{"value":{"ValueKind":1},"path":"/child","op":"add"}]
patchDocument.Add(path, element.GetRawText()); // Obviously treated as a string so fails and gives [{"value":"{\n       \"grandchild\": {\n       }\n     }","path":"/child","op":"add"}]
patchDocument.Add(path, element.GetString()); // Similar to the above attempt, but fails because element is an Object and throws exception. Attempting to replicate Newtonsoft's ToObject gives the next example
patchDocument.Add(path, netjson.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(element.GetRawText())); // Just a more convoluted version of our first attempt. Gives [{"value":{"ValueKind":1},"path":"/child","op":"add"}]
```

Here is working code that uses Newtonsoft.Json to take my JsonElement and produce the correct patch output. (but is very gross)

```
JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
JsonDocument newDocument = JsonDocument.Parse("{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"child\": {\"grandchild\": { } } }");
JsonElement parentObject = newDocument.RootElement;
JsonElement element = parentObject.GetProperty("child");

// This is more dynamic in real code, but hardcoded for example

patchDocument.Add("/", JObject.Parse(parentObject.GetRawText()).Property("child").Value); // Correct answer [{\"value\":{\"grandchild\":{}},\"path\":\"/\",\"op\":\"add\"}]
```

I can (and for the moment am) proceeding just using Newtonsoft.Json. But as that isn't really supposed to be the way of the future - is there a way to successfully provide the correct value to `JsonPatchDocument.Add` using `System.Text.Json`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible\feasible yet. Microsoft themselves didn't implement it yet and [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-8.0#add-support-for-json-patch-when-using-systemtextjson) developers to *Newtonsoft* if such functionality is needed.